# What's the real reason McClane only returned half of Quail's fee?

Tags: short-stories, philip-k-dick

In Philip Dick's short story "We Can Remember It For You Wholesale" we find this interesting passage:

> "No," McClane said. "And we're going to return half his fee."
>
> "'Half'! Why half?"
>
> McClane said lamely, "It seems to be a good compromise."

In the context of the story it seems like McClane is lying and that he has another reason for not returning the full fee. What is it?

Comment: He likes money and wants to keep as much of it as possible? :-)